# fonts rendering on phone are different and how to inspect on phone?

Tags: html, css

[image: on-chrome-inspector]
[image: on-phone]

I am having issues with fonts on my site. I am using:

```
font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
```

And it works fine for PC and desktop but on phone I am getting small cursive fonts.
I tried to use media query but it is not working

```
     /* Phone fonts*/
        /* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)     {
    body {
    font-weight:800!important;
        font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive!important;
font-size:20px;
}
}

/* iPhone [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body {
font-weight:800!important;
font-size:20px;
        font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive!important;
}
}
```

It is not taking any of these CSS styles.
When I inspect on chrome browser for iphone it works fine, but when I actually use my phone it is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the Fredoka One font is not installed on your phone.

Place the following line in the head section of your page to make it available:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One" rel="stylesheet">
```